# Why will my ExtJS tab will not show items with a border layout

Tags: javascript, layout, panel, extjs

As of right now I have a working tab panel in my website, and when I perform an action a tab gets added to the tabpanel.  Right now the tab renders all the items correctly with the following items definition

```
    return [{
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'north',
        autoHeight: true,
        items: this.buildToolbar()
    }, {
        xtype: 'panel',
        region: 'center',
        autoHeight: true,
        items: [{
            xtype: 'fieldset',
            title: 'Details:',
            collapsible: true,
            autoHeight: true,
            items: [this.detailForm]
        }]
    }];
```

However, I now want to add an eastern collapsible panel to this tab only, so in the panel's config I added `layout: 'border',`.  Now nothing is rendered inside of my tab.  If I then comment out my `layout` call, everything renders fine.

Why does nothing render when this panel is set to be a border layout?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove `autoHeight: true` (at every level -- don't **ever** use this inside a BorderLayout) and add `layout: 'fit'` to your center region.  Also, not sure that adding a form into your fieldset is what you want -- probably the other way around would make more sense.

Comment: Removing the auto-height didn't work, but your `layout: 'fit'` made me think.  I made the center region of the viewport (the panel that holds the TabPanel) have a layout: 'fit', and that fixed it!  Thanks!

Comment: As for the FieldSet outside of the form, I am doing that on purpose as a lightweight way to separate different components on the page.  Collapsible panels have too big of a header, and this seems to work better (asthetic wise at least)

Comment: `autoHeight:true` means "let the browser manage height based on contents". In Ext layouts in general, this is almost never what you want. In BorderLayouts, it is absolutely not what you want. And yes, you should always specify an appropriate layout at each level in a nested layout hierarchy.